# Handle the error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code which calculates the distance between current location to another location, which is working very fine but I wanted to add the error handling when user gives an invalid address then I wanted to print the error, 
I have tried to handle it. To do that I have used `else` clause when it goes into else clause then it throws an error.

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

Please assist.

I am passing target address from JSP session.

```
<html>
    <%
try
{
        HttpSession session_1 = request.getSession(false);       
    String address = session_1.getAttribute("address").toString(); 
    %>
    <body onLoad="getLocation()">

<p>Please wait..We are calculating the distance from <%=address%> to your current location..</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<!--
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
-->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";        
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {


var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "<%=address%>";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var R = 6371;
    var dLat = (latitude-position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var dLon = (longitude-position.coords.longitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos((position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos((latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; 

function displayLocation(latitude,longitude,distance,adr){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = 'GET';
//      var sourcelocation = "london";
        var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
        var async = true;

        request.open(method, url, async);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[0];
            //sourcelocation = address.formatted_address;

            document.write("<font face=calibri> Your Current Location :"+address.formatted_address+"<BR>Destination Address:"+adr+"<BR>Distance:"+distance+" Km</font>");            
          }


        };
            var retresults = "Source Location :"+address.formatted_address+" Destination Address:"+adr+" Distance:"+distance+" km";

        request.send();
      return retresults;

      };
var adr = address;
var home = displayLocation(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,d.toFixed(2),adr); 
//  alert(home);
} 
else{

        document.write("<font face=calibri>Sorry, We are not able to find out the destination address</font>");            
}

}); 

}
</script>
<%
} catch (Exception e)
{
    out.println("Oops. There is some problem to find out the address details");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one of your main problems is using `document.write` paired with asynchronous functions - also look in the developer tools console for any errors, they may give you a clue as to what you're doing wrong

Comment: I have checked the error "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened." when it goes in else clause

Comment: I got the solution. I have used below piece of code and it works for me.
  if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var xx = document.getElementById("demo");
xx.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Sorry, Unable to find out the destination.</span>';
        }

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases - including when `document.write` does work as well as when it doesn't - you are very often better off using

```
.innerHTML
```

instead.

In your script, you use `document.write` twice. In your second `document.write` statement, you have included `<br>` twice, so it's clear you want the output on multiple lines.

One approach is to include more *empty paragraphs* in the HTML markup. As things stand, you have

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

You can replace that with:

```
<p id="para1"></p>
<p id="para2"></p>
<p id="para3"></p>
```

and then edit the first part of your `javascript` to:

```
var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var para2 = document.getElementById("para2");
var para3 = document.getElementById("para3");
```

Further down the script this will enable you to replace

```
document.write("<font face=calibri> Your Current Location :"+address.formatted_address+"<BR>Destination Address:"+adr+"<BR>Distance:"+distance+" Km</font>");
```

with

```
para1.innerHTML = 'Your Current Location: ' + address.formatted_address;
para2.innerHTML = 'Destination Address: ' + adr;
para3.innerHTML = 'Distance: ' + distance + ' Km';
```

**Complete Example:**

```js
var para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var para2 = document.getElementById("para2");
var para3 = document.getElementById("para3");

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        para1.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";        
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {


var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "<%=address%>";
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var R = 6371;
    var dLat = (latitude-position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var dLon = (longitude-position.coords.longitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos((position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos((latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; 

function displayLocation(latitude,longitude,distance,adr){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = 'GET';
//      var sourcelocation = "london";
        var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
        var async = true;

        request.open(method, url, async);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[0];
            
            para1.innerHTML = 'Your Current Location: ' + address.formatted_address;
            para2.innerHTML = 'Destination Address: ' + adr;
            para3.innerHTML = 'Distance: ' + distance + ' Km';          
          }


        };
            var retresults = "Source Location :"+address.formatted_address+" Destination Address:"+adr+" Distance:"+distance+" km";

        request.send();
      return retresults;

      };
var adr = address;
var home = displayLocation(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,d.toFixed(2),adr); 
} 

else {

        para1.innerHTML = 'Sorry, We are not able to find out the destination address';       
}

}); 

}
```

```html
<p>Please wait..We are calculating the distance from <%=address%> to your current location..</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="para1"></p>
<p id="para2"></p>
<p id="para3"></p>
```